# HTML5 Android App loaded via WebView, Identify links to open in app vs in Browser

Tags: android, html

I have an android app that is an HTML5 app that is displayed using a webview with some additional functionality around it.  The app is developed using a single page (jQuery Mobile) which loads the pages async, so it works fairly well to keep the navigation within the "App window" (WebView).

The issue I am running into is that there are links within the app that I would like to be opened in the device browser, but other links or navigation in the app to change pages, or refresh pages in the app (via javascript) sometimes try to open the app up in a browser.  It seems to be somewhat related to the method (JavaScript, Post, etc.) that makes the page open in a browser, however it's somewhat inconsistent.

I know there are ways in the android app to identify that The app should always open links in the app.  However, I'd like to control what happens in the app, and what links are directed to the browser. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For specific links that you want to open in your app- make them with specific pattern or from specific host, then in your Manifest file, put this code in your activity:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
    <data android:host="yourhost" android:scheme="http"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

the problem is that android will give the user the option to choose where to open this link (in the browser or in your app), and I'm afraid it's not what you want to do.

Comment: Are you saying by implementing the code above that Android will then prompt the user where to open the link?  Can you explain what the code above actually does?

Comment: Ah, I understand the intent-filter now.  You are right, I'd rather the user not have to select my app to continue using the app the way I intend it to be used.